# How to turn a string's length into a byte?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a client to connect to a chat server that's running erlang, which parses everything as bytes. I can connect to the server successfully.

However, the server administrator keeps telling me I'm getting my format wrong. I think I have things finally nailed down, but I come across an unusual issue; when I try to convert the length of the message's contents, it comes out horribly incorrect (the closest I got was with hex, and it still turned out as "31" which is over 30 characters off too long).

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii
host = 'jimmyr.com'    # The remote host
port = 12345              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send('\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04Omio') # This works.
data = s.recv(1024)
print repr(data)+"\n" # From server, I get '\x00\x01\x00\x0eYou connected!'
message = raw_input("Message to send at chat [!!! to quit]")
mlength = str(len(message))
print repr(data)+"\n"
while str(message) != "!!!":
    if str(message) != "":
        s.send('\x00\x01\x00\x01'+(str(len(message)).encode("hex")+str(message).encode("hex")))
        message = raw_input("Message to send to chat [!!! to quit]")
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print repr(data)+"\n"
    else:
    print repr(data)+"\n"
#EoF
```

In terms of what response I need to make, please see [the server's protocol specification](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cXfeIe-YDg5qLsfQ7L7Qw0qRiJ3yyuYekmd8ynGJ_OQ/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the hex representations in the specification mean. The spec uses hex to show binary values. The key line is `Everything non-text will be 2 byte long`. So, your message length needs to be encoded as a two-byte (big-endian) binary value. You don't want your string to be encoded in hex either, but rather to send it as a plain bytestring.

I think you want to `send` this:

```
struct.pack(">HHH", 1, 1, len(message)) + message
```

This uses `struct.pack` to handle the "server ID" and "packet code" numbers as well as the length, which should be rather nicer than needing to encode those other bits by hand. The `>` code means to use big-endian encoding, and the three `H`s say to pack up three "unsigned short" (two-byte) integers.

Comment: Mind elaborating on what the '>HHH' does? Also, thanks for tweaking my question. Will test your answer before confirming it. [=

Comment: @Omio: I've updated the answer with an extra sentence explaining the `>HHH` bit. You may want to look over the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)'s documentation for more details.

Comment: Nope, got it perfectly. Thanks. Wish I could upvote you for the answer.